# what's the default state of a newly opened terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, serial-port, posix

I have the following functions in Linux,

```
#include <termios.h>

struct termios s;
int fd=open("/dev/ttyO0",O_RDWR);
tcgetattr( fd,&s);
```

And what's will be content in `s`, or in another word, whats the state of my `ttyO0` terminal( a serial terminal) which is referred by `fd`. Is there a default state for a newly opened terminal, since the fd is brand new now. Please also let me know where to find the related document.

Comment: The attributes will be the previous configuration.

Comment: @sawdust so what about I just boot up, is there a default attribute?

Comment: Maybe.  But why should it matter?  For proper operation, the program should configure the comm port to the specific attributes it needs, regardless of what the previous setup was.  The one rule that is often violated is that the "unused"/undefined bits and bytes of the `termios` structure should not be modified.  That code may work today, but may break on another system or after the next system update.

Comment: Yes there are default terminal characteristics which are stored on the system. The current terminal settings are available using `stty -a`.